# Remove public from url hosted in sub domain in Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have hosted my Laravel site in sub domain, its url is something like this:

> https://mymaindomain.com/subfolder/public/about-us

Now i want to remove the public from url,
my .htaccess file is like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/beta [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What happens when you go to https://mymaindomain.com/subfolder/about-us ?

Comment: @apokryfos : I get 404 not found

Comment: In a subdomain or a subfolder? For a subdomain you should set up a VirtualHost with `public` being the DocumentRoot of that VirtualHost

Comment: and if it is in subfolder what i have to modify

Comment: Try moving [the existing Laravel .htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) from subfolder/public to subfolder and changing the line `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]`

Comment: I have tried but still same issue

Comment: did you solved your problem ? i have the same issue in my subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Move your all files from `/public` to your root folder `/` (which mainly your laravel folder).

Now open `index.php` file and edit 2 lines, as below :

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
// changed to
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
// changed to
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Now add this lines to your `.htaccess` to prevent access `.env` from URL :

```
<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

By this method you can host your laravel app in any kind of shared hosting too.

Hope this helps