# In Laravel my live site can also access with /public so does that bad for SEO?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, public

I have Laravel 6 site to be going to live and my concern is my site also can be open from the `/public` so does that affect in SEO of a site? I don't want to change root's `server.php` to `index.php` or move all the files and folders of the public to root. Because that can be unsafe.

Comment: Why don't you change the root path from your apache/nginx server?

Comment: There is a alternative way, 
And this is safe  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62127877/4575350